# How to render an array from a POST request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't get this to work unfortunately and would very much appreciate some help :)

I get an array via POST request and want the elements of the array to be rendered in a list. I get the array, but it is not updating the useState as intended.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ShowFiles = () => {

    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    useEffect( () => {     
        fetch("https://--------------/getFiles", {
             headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
              method: 'POST',
              crossDomain:true,
        })
        .then( results => results.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log("items:", data)
            setList(data)
            console.log("list:", list)
        })
       
    },[])

    return (

           
           <div>
            
           {list.map(({item}) => (
               <ul>{item}</ul>
           ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the above example the list-variable stayed empty.

So I learned that useEffect needs a dependency variable, so I added "list" as such, which passed the array to the list-variable but it wouldn't stop making the POST request, so also not a solution.

Any idea in which direction I can get this to work?

Comment: *"the list-variable stayed empty"* - What specific observation shows this?  The line `console.log("list:", list)` is a mistake, but it won't prevent the component from working in general.  Do you mean that the component itself never re-renders?  And that `data` has been observed to indeed contain an array?  Are there any errors in the browser's development console?

Comment: It's normal that you don't get the list data when you console log it in the useEffect because state updates are asynchronous but I don't see why  the component itself wouldn't work please what does the console.log("items:" data) put in the console?

Comment: you can check the putting the `log` outside the effect ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `list` as a dependency in that particular `useEffect` because it will just create an endless loop by fetching and then refreshing the dom and the cycle continues.

You can resolve this by adding a new `useEffect` for `list` like so

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(list);
}, [list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `{item}` in place of `item` in `.map` function. It should be like this

```
<div>
            
           {list.map((item) => (
               <ul>{item}</ul>
           ))}
        </div>
```

Remove those extra curly `{}` braces

Comment: Unless the intent is to render a single property called `item` on each object in the array.  We don't know, and the OP hasn't clarified anything.